# Need help solving unserialize():Error at offset

Tags: drupal, error, mysql

Thank you all for your continued patience with me.

Since the past two updates, I keep getting the following error:

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 8 bytes in Civi\Core\SettingsBag->loadValues() (line 153 of /home/[usrpath]/public_html/[sitedirectory]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsBag.php).

I know this is related to a mySQL database problem, but for the life of me I cannot figure this out.

I am running CiviCRM 4.7.14 on Drupal 7.52

Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

This line reads the data from the table `civicrm_setting` and specifically the column `value`.  You could use a SQL client to run the query:

```
SELECT id, name, value FROM civicrm_setting;
```

Typical values would look these:

- `NULL`
- `i:0;` (an integer)
- `b:1;` (a boolean?)
- `s:20:"CRM/common/fatal.tpl";` (a string)
- `a:1:{s:3:"key";s:5:"value";}` (an array or dictionary)

Skim them and see if one of the values looks to have a different/unexpected format.

---

(UPDATE) Seamus Lee pointed me to https://www.drupal.org/node/1114304 which uses a clever technique for finding badly serialized data. Take the error message (`Error at offset 0 of 8 bytes`) and note the length (8 bytes). Search on that:

```
SELECT id, name, value FROM civicrm_setting WHERE length(value) = 8;
```

Comment: All but 3 entries are in the format of s:1:"3"; where the number in quotes varies.  There are 2 entries where instead of a number in quotes there is a comma, and one where there is a period/dot. Other than that they are all the same:

Comment: id    name                                          value
17   max_attachments                       s:1:"3";
18   contact_undelete                        s:1:"1";
19   empoweredBy                             s:1:"0";
20   logging                                        s:1:"1";
21   maxFileSize                                 s:1:"3";
22   doNotAttachPDFReceipt             s:1:"1";
23 secondDegRelPermissions            s:1:"0";
24 checksum_timeout                         s:1:"7";
31 dedupe_default_limit                     s:1:"0";
32 remote_profile_submissions          s:1:"0";

Comment: 40 fieldSeparator                                s:1:",";  <---- comma
41 inheritLocale                                  s:1:"0";
44 monetaryThousandSeparator        s:1:",";  <---- comma
45 monetaryDecimalPoint                   s:1:".";  <---- period/dot
58 contact_smart_group_display        s:1:"1";
72 hideCountryMailingLabels              s:1:"1";
83 enable_innodb_fts                          s:1:"0";
84 includeWildCardInName                 s:1:"1";

Comment: 85 includeEmailInName                       s:1:"1";
86 includeNickNameInName               s:1:"0";
87 includeAlphabeticalPager               s:1:"1";
88 includeOrderByClause                   s:1:"1";
89 smartGroupCacheTimeout             s:1:"5";

Comment: This editor makes me crazy.  Pressing enter (when trying to add a new line adds the comment and I don't have permissions to edit my own comments!  Also, The comments do not seem to honor a carriage return so the list is not at all helpful. Not sure how to set this up so people can actually make sense of the return results.

Comment: Yeah, I find that frustrating too. For longer technical, it may be easier to put the data on a site like https://gist.github.com/ or http://paste2.org/ or http://pastebin.com/ -- then just link it.